# Streaming on-demand data on to Kafka topics based on consumer requests

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, ksqldb

We are a source system and we have a couple of downstream systems which would require our data for their needs, currently we are publishing events onto **Kafka topics** as and when there is a change in source system for them to consume and make changes to their tables (all delta updates)

Our downstream systems is currently accessing our **database** directly sometimes to make complete refresh of their tables on demand basis once in a while to make sure data is in sync apart from subscribing to Kafka topics, as you know we always need a data refresh sometimes when we feel data is out of sync for some reason.

We are planning to stop giving access to our database directly, how can we achieve this ? Is there a way that consumers request us their data needs by any triggers like passing request to us and we can publish the stream of data for them to consume on their end and they sync the tables or get the bulk data into their memory to perform some tasks based on their needs.

We currently have written RESTful APIs to provide data based on the requests, but we are exposing small data volumes as I think APIs we only send smaller volumes of data, but it won't work when we want to send millions of data to consumers and I believe only way is to stream data on Kafka, but with Kafka how can we respond to the request from consumers and only pump that specific data on to Kafka topics for them to consume ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the option of setting the retention policy on any topic to keep messages forever with:

`retention.ms: -1`

[see the docs](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs_retention.ms)

In that case you could store the entire change log in the same manner that you currently are. Then if a consumer needs to re-materialize the entire history, they can start with the first offset and go from there without you having to produce a specialized dataset.

Comment: Thanks sarwar, but if there is any special request from consumer that they want to send a request to get data pumped on to a topic and batch job would consume the data and copy the data into staging tables, is there a way to do it ?, demand something and we pump data on to topics and consumer can run batch process to get data on their end ?

Comment: No, I don't believe that sort of thing is supported. If the data the consumer needs was in a topic before but is no longer, you can change your retention policy. If the data was never in a topic before a consumer needs it, you can consider changing what you produce to Kafka. But I'd argue that if you absolutely need ad-hoc materialization of an arbitrary dataset to a topic for a single-use read, then Kafka might be the wrong tool for the job. In your case, I would put everything into Kafka and let the consumer either read from the head if they need the newest, or from start if they need it all